# UPnP Mapping wrong Endpoints?

Tags: c#, ip, nat, portforwarding, upnp

I'm tring to do something called "[Port Forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding)" using UPnP Com assemply in c# , the following code works fine and map new external ip and port number to my device , but it seems that the ip is not my correct external ip number , because it is different from the one I get in IP-lookup websites like ([whatismyipaddress.com](http://whatismyipaddress.com/) and [whatismyip.com](https://www.whatismyip.com/)) .

this is my c# code (for the mapping) :

```
NATUPNPLib.UPnPNATClass upnpnat = new NATUPNPLib.UPnPNATClass();
NATUPNPLib.IStaticPortMappingCollection mappings = upnpnat.StaticPortMappingCollection;
mappings.Add(20000, "UDP", 20000, "192.168.8.102", true, "Local Web Server");
foreach (NATUPNPLib.IStaticPortMapping portMapping in mappings)
{
    Console.WriteLine(portMapping.Description); //gives me "Local Web Server"
    Console.WriteLine(portMapping.ExternalIPAddress); // gives me "10.178.196.123"
    Console.WriteLine(portMapping.Enabled); // gives me "True"
}
```

in Ip-looking websites I got another external IP (46.32.126.221) , I tried to map my device with additional tools like [UPnP Wizard](http://www.xldevelopment.net/upnpwiz.php) and I got the same problem .

can you help me please ?

Comment: did you specify the correct interface with your C# code ? it possible that the external ip mapping to incorrect interface

Comment: I did choose the interface that currently have the internet connection

Comment: Your routers external IP is still in a private address range: either your have another NAT device (maybe a cable modem or something like it) on the way or your Internet provider has one.

Comment: @jku then how I can work this out in your opinion ?

Comment: For the devices in your control, you could try  changing their settings (e.g. define a port mapping or set device in "switch mode"  if that's available). If the NAT is in your ISPs control,  you could try paying them more to get a real IP.

Comment: @jku it seems that the problem isn't with port forwarding but with something else , because torrent works finely but not others , I guess it a problem with windows firewall

Comment: To be fair, you haven't actually defined what your problem is so far.  I just tried to help with the reasons for different IPs, the only issue you mentioned in the post...

Comment: I'm so sorry , surely I'm confusing you , the thought that the problem was with port forwarding , but I realized that it with something else , I guess it something related with windows firewalls . I start losing my hope